# How to get the list of table names from database in sorted order according to there creation date?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am using MySQL Database. I have a database which contains tables. The number of tables are not constantin database. In my application there is a process which creats a new table into the database. I want to show these tablesnames in JComboBox.

I used following query to retrieve the table names.

show tables in dbinfo;

Now I want to retrieve the table names in sorted order.  But the sorting should be done according to the creation date of the table.

is there any query which gives result as I required.

Thanks You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT table_name,Create_time FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'yourDataBaseName' order by Create_time asc;
```

Comment: I already tried above query. I checked in database list It dont shows the database named "information_schema" I think some one has deleted this database and all its tables from my dbserver. Is there any alternet way to get the information?

Comment: if Information_schema is not there then, try `show table status` it has 'create_time' field, but you cannot order by that, that should be done in php.

Comment: Thank You! Your solution gives me at least the information that I want. But as per your comment you says that to getting the order by 'crate_time' resultset is possible in PHP. Can you explain how its possible in PHP so that I will try the same in Java.

Comment: show table status has all the fields, from the recordset copy only the required fields into an array and sort by one of the fields.

Answer (score 3):

Every MySQL db has a [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) and it [one of the tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html) (INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES) has the data about tables. You can fire the query and get the table as per our needs. e.g.

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  where table_schema = 'empinfo' order by CREATE_TIME desc
```

Comment: Thank You Sir! for your reply. I used above query but it gives all the table name in my database server. Actually I want the list of tables sorted according to there creation date from a perticular database on my database server. For example I have "empinfo" databse on my DBserver which have 10 tables. So I want these 10 tables name list sorted according to there creation date from database "empinfo" on my DB Server

Comment: you can add table_schema to where clause. I have updated the query in my answer.

Comment: Thank You Sir! I tried by adding where clause which works fine on my local machine. But when I execute the same query on my Main Database server it gives me an error message Error Code : 1146 Table 'information_schema.TABLES' doesn't exist (32 ms taken) is there any alternet way to get the table names?

Comment: `information_schema` is pretty standard schema on MySQL. Please check with you Database administrator if that schema exists on your Main Database or there is any permission issue with your username.

Comment: I checked in database list. It dont shows the database named "information_schema" I think some one has deleted this database and all its tables from my dbserver. I am logging in to DB server as root user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`information_schema.TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html) to get table data by their creation date as:

```
SELECT table_name, create_time FROM information_schema.TABLES 
      where table_schema='myTableSchema' order by create_time;
```

Remove create_time column to only get table names. You can also change the ordering.
Here `myTableSchema` is your database name, ***don't forget to use where condition otherwise it will get table names of all schema available on db server***.

Comment: Thank You Sir! I used your query but When I execute your query It gives me an error message                               Error Code : 1146
Table 'information_schema.TABLES' doesn't exist
(32 ms taken)
is there any alternet way to get the table names?

Comment: @Param-Ganak First execute `FLUSH TABLES` to refresh table cache and then try again with this query.

Comment: I checked in database list It dont shows the database named "information_schema" I think some one has deleted this database and all its tables from my dbserver. I think because of this it is giving an above error. The command you have suggested i.e. FLUSH TABLES; is it make any massive changes to my DB server. Because I am directly working on my live server.

Comment: @Param-Ganak FLUSH TABLES forces all tables in use to be closed, and flushes the query cache. It also removes all query results from the query cache.

Answer (score -1):

Select tables from (tablename) order by (date_field) desc.

Comment: I am not retrieving table names from a table. I want to retrieve name of tables from database.

Comment: use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES instead tables... select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES order by create_time desc